# ReactFX Consumer listening to more than one EventStream

Tags: java, events, javafx, reactive-programming, reactfx

This question is perhaps aimed at the creator of *ReactFX*, but others are welcome to answer.

I am currently starting to use *ReactFX* for data sharing and event handling within a *JavaFX* application. My question is how can a class subscribe to listen to events from two(or more) different `EventStreams`. Suppose that in a `Controller class` I have a `textfield` that may be updated with a `new text(String)`, so this class would implement `Consumer<String>`. But then you may also want for this `textfield` to be updated with a `new Integer` (for example) coming from a totally different source, so it would have to implement `Consumer<Integer>`, only you can't do that because it already implements `Consumer<String>`.

I thought about creating a bundle class with an id field(with an `Enum` for example) and an `Object field` containing the data, lets name it `ReactFXEventBundle`. Only instances of this class will be able to be used as `Events`, where the consumer can identify the type of Event by analyzing the id field. Therefore, all Consumer classes would implement `Consumer<ReactFXEventBundle>`. Would this be the right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure we are on the same page, I assume your situation looks something like this

```
class Controller {
    TextField getTextField();
}

EventStream<String> strings;
EventStream<Integer> integers;
```

and you want to route both `strings` and `integers` to TextField's `textProperty()`. This is how you do that:

```
EventStreams.merge(
    strings,
    integers.map(Integer::toString)
).feedTo(controller.getTextField().textProperty());
```

In words, you convert the stream of integers to a stream of strings, merge the two string streams and *feed* the merged stream into the text property of the field. (`feedTo(property)` is just a shorthand for `subscribe(property::set)`).

Note that your controller class doesn't have to implement `Consumer` directly. The consumer instance is created from the `property::set` method reference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it will definitely make me think about all the possibilities using EventStream combinations!